# Why @Input and @Output decorators declared inside class? Why not outside class like @Component?

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

Can anybody explain why `@Input` and `@output` decorators declared inside the class, can't we declare it outside the class like `@Component`?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'my-component', 
})

class MyComponent {  
    @Input() name: string;  
    @Input() age: number;

    @Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;
}
```

Comment: Because it's the logical thing to do? How would you tell, with a decorator on the component, which fields are inputs and outputs?

Comment: In and outputs are given through the template there is no template available outside of the component.

Comment: Yes and you can even put a decorator on a method. You would need to have many decorator properties.

Answer (score 1):

The decorators are not stand-alone entities, they decorate other entities.

In the case of inputs and outputs, they are decorating class member variables.

Class member variables are, by definition, in the class, so that's where the decorators must go.